# WordPress wp_nav_menu is not working in header and footer file in WordPress 5.6 version

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook, custom-wordpress-pages

I have tried to display menu in header and footer file but I got below error.

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\wp-includes\class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 153
```

I used below code in footer and header file.

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
    'theme_location'  => 'footer',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu-wrapper',
    'container_class' => 'primary-menu-container',
    'items_wrap'      => '',
    'fallback_cb'     => false,
    )
);
```

I have also tried to simple way like

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) );
```

But it's always showing **waning** in WordPress version 5.6.

Someone please help me how can i resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

if you use something like that:

```
function change_menu_item_css_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if($args->menu === 'Main'){
        $classes = ['your_class'];
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

don't forget add else

```
function change_menu_item_css_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if($args->menu === 'Main'){
        $classes = ['your_class'];
        return $classes;
    } else {return [''];}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this piece of code in there:

```
'theme_location'  => 'footer'
```

Did you actually assign your navigation menu to a menu location called "footer" (or "header" for your second example) in the WP backend (under "Settings > Menus > Menu Positions")?